# How to create html URL to open LotusNotes and populate To and Subject fields

Tags: html, url, lotus-notes

I'm working on new internal web portal where I need for service support put mailto: link that will open Lotus Notes and populate To and Subject fields.

I found on internet url: notes:///0000000000000E00/Memo?OpenForm but it just open Notes and create new mail without populating any fields.
There are method with create hotspot link (notes:///serverID/viewID/noteID) but it open already created document on my Notes. I need user who visit a web portal click on link and all necessary fields would be already populated.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Tommy

Answer (score 1):

If notes is the default mail client you can use the default mailto: like

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

Comment: This is something I could not know how users setup trey's computer.
If you read my post careful you would see I looking for solution that ensure Lotus Notes will be open on URL click.
I know syntax for "mailto:", that is not question.

Comment: If it is an internal app, something like gpo should make sure that Notes is the default mail client. on the otherhand it's mail, why care what client is used ?

Comment: I have this situation. Network is internal but users are from different domains which is not under my control.. Also, Notes is very unfriendly software that is not easily to control with GPO. However, I see clear my situation and if there would be option to use mailto: I would not losing time ask support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in the notes:// URL syntax for doing what you want. So if you really can't use mailto:, you would have to write some javascript that uses the Notes OLE classes (notes.NotesUIWorkspace and possibly also notes.NotesSession, but not lotus.NotesSession because that's for the COM classes, not OLE) in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi..
sounds complicate....I may give up and find another way to receive messages from users. Thank you for your response.